# How can i get Oracle number values to .NET without Zeros?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, numbers, decimal

i try to read Data from an Oracle-Database.
The problem is that in some cases the receiving data adds Zeros after the digit and i dont know why this happens?!?

For example i want to read Data like this

1

1,1

1,12

1,123

When i read it with Oracle-Datareader i get

1

1,10   <-

1,12

1,1230  <-

Everytime the decimal places are 1,3,5,7 long it adds one 0 in the result.
But why is this happening??
Does anyone know this kind of problem?

**EDIT:**

```
Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(Select_Statement, Connection)

Dim dr As OracleDataReader

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


While dr.Read()

            If dr("C1").ToString = V1 Then

                Me.Txt_1.Text = dr.GetDecimal(3).ToString("G0")

                Me.Txt_2.Text = dr(c4)

                Me.Txt_3.Text = dr(c5)

                Me.Txt_4.Text = dr(c6)


            End If

            If dr("C2").ToString = V2 Then

                Me.Txt_5.Text = dr(c3)

                Me.Txt_6.Text = dr(c4)

                Me.Txt_7.Text = dr(c5)

                Me.Txt_8.Text = dr(c6)


            End If

        End While

dr.Close()
```

This is the way i read the data from the database, if there is a better way i would be happy about some tips! Because the way with dr.GetDecimal() only excepts numbers for row indexing.

Comment: How exactly is this a problem unless you're storing your numbers in strings, which is a problem itself?

Comment: what is the precision on the field in the oracle DB?

Comment: The precision and Scale is not set, it is null, Data_length is 22

Comment: THe problem is that i read the values and show them in a Textbox, there i get 1,90 when i save 1,9 in the database, but i want to become 1,9 into the Texbox without converting with CDbl. There must be a solution in database or oracedatareader itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the C# and not in the DB.

From the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx):

> If format is null or an empty string, the return value of this
>   instance is formatted with the general numeric format specifier (G)

The `general format` contain the zero you want to avoid.
If you want to remove it, just do:

```
string sd = dr.GetDecimal(0).ToString("G0");
```

Where dr is my OracleDataReader

Comment: OK, thank you, now i understand, but this is the same result like working with CDbl(), is there any general option to set this behaviour in the whole project for datareader with toString for numbers?