# c#: Oracle/OracleDataReader adds additional '0' after decimal point if amount of comma numbers equals scale

Tags: c#, oracle, decimal, datareader

I found some strange behavior when retrieving data from my Oracle database. I've got a table field defined as NUMBER(20,3).

```
var ordinal = 100;
var decimalValue = _reader[ordinal];                    //100.1550
OracleDecimal decVal = (_reader as DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader)?.GetOracleDecimal(ordinal);
string decString = decVal.toString();                   //100.155
Console.WriteLine(decVal.Value);                        //100.1550
```

While retrieving a value from OracleDataReader with a value like 100.10 it works fine (toString will return 100.10). But when the amount of comma numbers equals the scale(3) like 100.155 an additional 0 will be added making the value 100.1550. In my perception this additional 0 should not be added due to the scale, but the fact is it does. Perhaps the value is stored as 110.1550 in Oracle?

My question is, why is this 0 added while the scale is 3 and how can I retrieve this value correctly from the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get Oracle number values to .NET without Zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981003/how-can-i-get-oracle-number-values-to-net-without-zeros)

Comment: Thank you @John for the quick reply. I did not know about this toString behavior. The value retrieved from the _reader[ordinal] is of type decimal. This does not explain why the 0 is added right?