# OracleDataReader[columnName] return wrong decimal places

Tags: c#, odp.net

I have a table which has a Column defined as 'Number(18,3)'. Then I insert `123.123` value for this column.

When I select it in 'Oracle Sql Developer', it shows correctlly. (123.123)

But if I read it in c# by using `OracleDataReader` of the ODP.NET, it will return '123.1230'. I did not understand this behavior.

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981003/how-can-i-get-oracle-number-values-to-net-without-zeros